# ViewPager overlaps AppBarLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to setup a layout for an `Activity` that will contain N `Fragments`. In the layout I've used a `ViewPager` and an `AppBarLayout`, the problem I'm facing is that the `ViewPager` overlaps the `AppBarLayout` as you can see from the screenshot:

[image]

This is my `activity_main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />


<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:id="@+id/containter">

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

And this is my `app_bar_main.xml` which contains the `AppBarLayout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.app.app.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

How can I prevent these elements from overlapping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Signo,

Your problem could be solved with some layout adjustments.

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include
            layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:id="@+id/containter" />
        </android.support.v4.view.DrawerLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks :) I've tried and it almost worked out, I had to change the `android:layout_height` of the `include` element to `wrap_content` and now the overlapping is gone

Comment: That's nice, would be amazing if you edit your question to add your solution :) @Signo

Comment: If you don't mind I've edited your answer so I can accept it :) Again, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

first of all try to add a viewGroup above your views something like :

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
 //... your views here
 </RelativeLayout>
```

and you should change the height of your appBar to `wrap_content` and add some id

```
<include
            android:id="@+id/app_bar_id"
            layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

and then on your view pager define the layout_below attribute like this :

```
  <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/containter"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar_id"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
```